# Who is this gorilla that carried Sengoku on its shoulder?

Tags: one-piece

I'm sorry to ask this, but I'm little curious about this picture, here Sengoku seem riding on a gorilla.

**I don't know how far in anime, so I put the picture as spoiler.**

> [image]

Who is this gorilla, is this Sengoku's new pet? I only remember that he has a goat as a pet.

I don't think it's Kong -of course not-

Comment: Who do you mean by Kong?

Comment: @solalito sorry for late response, here's [Kong](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the gorilla that was transformed to a [toy](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hobi_Hobi_no_Mi).

From the chapter 743:

> [image]

Comment: Oh, I guess he's come with Sengoku...